# Android Photo Picker set tick for already selected uri's previously

Tags: android, activityresultcontracts, photo-picker

Reference to the feature -> https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker#device-availability

**Code and explanation I**

I create a request which will open up photo and video picker, after selecting a list of uri's is returned in the listener

```
    PickVisualMediaRequest request =
            new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
                    .setMediaType(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageAndVideo.INSTANCE)
                    .build();
    pickVisualMediaRequestActivityResultLauncher.launch(request);
```

**Code and explanation II**

The following code registers Listener for Activity result and is executed when photos/videos are selected using Photo picker

```
pickVisualMediaRequestActivityResultLauncher =
                registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(10),
                        result -> {
                            //Handling Here what to do with result (List<Uri>)
                        }
                );
```

The problem is I've given the limit of 10 to mediafiles in the PickMultipleVisualMedia's constructor, user selects 5 items and comes back to locally created preview screen and then decides to select remaining 5 items then there is no way I could find to make those 5 files already selected in the photo picker, no way to pass the already selected uris to the picker function, user has to select all the 10 files again, is there any solution for this? Because I couldn't find any function in Picker class that would allow me to do so.